# SUMIFS function from other workbook - Error is Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to do `SUMIFS` function in a range of active sheet from other workbook. Here is where I get my error of Macro:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(6, lastCol + 1),
                  ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol + 1)).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(" ' " & wbGSD.Name & "'!$F$10:$F$" & wbGSDlastRow & ",'" & wbGSD.Name & "'!$B$10:$B$" & wbGSDlastRow & ",B6,'" & wbGSD.Name & "'!$C$10:$C$" & wbGSDlastRow & ", Total")
```

The error I got is:

> Type Mismatch

I tried `Sumif` function. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `SumIfs()` one long string. It doesn't take one long string. It takes a number of parameters, the first two of which are `Range` objects, not strings. If you want to write your formula as one long *string*, then there's no need for `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs()`. Just assign the string formula to the range's `Formula` property:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=SUMIFS('" & wbGSD.Name & "'!$F$10:$F$" & ...
```

If you really *do* want to use `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs()`, you'll need to use it properly by passing individual parameters of the right type:

```
Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
    Sheets(wbGSD.Name).Range("$F$10:$F$" & wbGSDlastRow), _
    Sheets(wbGSD.Name).Range("$B$10:$B$" & wbGSDlastRow), _
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks Bond! <3 <3 <3 That was what I did on your first suggestion, and now I realized that I missed a comma... hehehe... happy now.. ^^ Thanks!

Comment: If you found the answer useful, consider [upvoting or accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).